# Simple regex matching in BigQuery not working

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables available in BigQuery:

- `my-project.my-database.what-to-query`:

```
+---------+-----------+
| id_what | name_what |
+---------+-----------+
|    1    |   C++     |
+---------+-----------+
|    2    |   Foo     |
+---------+-----------+
|    3    |   Ca$h    |
+---------+-----------+
```

- `my-project.my-database.where-to-query`:

```
+----------+----------------------+
| id_where |      name_where      |
+----------+----------------------+
|    4     | C++ and Ca$h         |
+----------+----------------------+
|    5     | Foo Fighters is nice |
+----------+----------------------+
|    6     | I know C# and C++    |
+----------+----------------------+
|    7     | Football is cool     |
+----------+----------------------+
|    8     | Don't have anything  |
+----------+----------------------+
```

I would like to use `name_what` as a REGEX search keyword, to obtain all the matches in `name_where`, while keeping all the columns. The result should look like:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------+
| id_what | name_what | id_where |      name_where      |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------+
|    1    |   C++     |    4     | C++ and Ca$h         |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------+
|    1    |   C++     |    6     | I know C# and C++    |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------+
|    2    |   Foo     |    5     | Foo Fighters is nice |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------+
|    2    |   Foo     |    7     | Football is cool     |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------+
|    3    |   Ca$h    |    4     | C++ and Ca$h         |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------+
```

Notice how `C++` should be escaped, something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `my-project.my-database.where-to-query`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(name, r"C\+\+")
```

BUT the thing is that column `name_what` could keep several OTHER strings (i.e., IRL, both tables contain hundreds of thousands of rows, this is only a toy sample), which would contain OTHER RegEx special characters. In **Python** for instance, you have [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to deal with this specific problem, but nothing similar in SQL / BigQuery.

With comment's aid, I have tried the following **updated** code:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ENCODE_WITH_ESCAPE(x STRING) RETURNS STRING AS (
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(x, "+", "\\\\+"), "$", "\\\\$"
    )  -- For the time being, only "+" & "$" have been dealt with, there could be more
);

WITH what AS (
      SELECT 1 AS id_what, 'c++' AS name_what UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2 AS id_what, 'foo' AS name_what UNION ALL 
      SELECT 3 AS id_what, 'ca$h' AS name_what

    ),
    andwhere AS (
      SELECT 4 AS id_where, 'C++ and Ca$h' AS name_where UNION ALL 
      SELECT 5 AS id_where, 'Foo Fighters is nice' AS name_where UNION ALL 
      SELECT 6 AS id_where, 'I know C# and C++' AS name_where UNION ALL 
      SELECT 7 AS id_where, 'Football is cool' AS name_where UNION ALL 
      SELECT 8 AS id_where, "Don't have anything" AS name_where

    ) 

    SELECT * 
    FROM what JOIN andwhere 
    ON REGEXP_CONTAINS(ENCODE_WITH_ESCAPE(andwhere.name_where), ENCODE_WITH_ESCAPE(what.name_what))
```

The previous code run, with the output: `There is no data to display`.

How to combine all the requirements?

PS.: BigQuery's *"Legacy SQL"* can NOT be an answer.

Comment: Based on your error, your problem is that the + operator used in name_what  = C++ is an pattern chracter for regex. Try to replace + for \+  ( you are actually declaring that + is an special character  and not a pattern to follow). + in regex means "this pattern could be repeated 1 or more times"

Comment: I am aware of that @Tom , however there could be other DIFFERENT RegEx strings, so hardcoding is not an option. Something more robust is needed. (PD.: I have updated the problem description, hopefully it is clearer this time). Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I see  you updated the question, nice. But in this case why would you need to use regex ? Cant you use CONTAINS_SUBSTR ( see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions ) for this purpose instead ?

Comment: @Tom: `CONTAINS_SUBSTR` does **nicely** _when trying with "C++" as test string_, we are almost there! However, when I tried `SELECT * FROM 'my-project.my-database.what-to-query' c, 'my-project.my-database.where-to-query' s WHERE CONTAINS_SUBSTR(skill_table.name, course_table.name)`, I stumble upon the error `Argument 2 to DREMELGOOGLESQL:CONTAINS_SUBSTR must be a literal or query parameter at [3:41]` which does not allow me to start running the query. Any hints?

Comment: Did you try to convert the parameter search_value_literal from CONTAINS_SUBSTR(expression, search_value_literal)  to string at first? I.E The docs says that NULL, and no mixed data is allowed, so try to convert it as string first . This is my last shot haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below option

```
create temp function escapeRegExp(x string) 
returns string language js
as r"return x.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');";
with what as (
  select 1 as id_what, 'c++' as name_what union all 
  select 2 as id_what, 'foo' as name_what union all 
  select 3 as id_what, 'ca$h' as name_what
), andwhere as (
  select 4 as id_where, 'C++ and Ca$h' as name_where union all 
  select 5 as id_where, 'Foo Fighters is nice' as name_where union all 
  select 6 as id_where, 'I know C# and C++' as name_where union all 
  select 7 as id_where, 'Football is cool' as name_where union all 
  select 8 as id_where, "Don't have anything" as name_where
)
select *
from what join andwhere
on regexp_contains(lower(name_where), escapeRegExp(lower(name_what)))
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this function from Mikhail that replaces all those special characters will work just fine if your data has all sorts of such characters.

Comment: @Mikhail, this is exactly what I was looking for! Didn't know JavScripts UDFs (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure) were a thing! "Every day you learn something new" certainly fits this case, haha. Thank you very much, I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps:

```
create temp function encode_with_escape(x STRING) returns string as (
    replace(x, "+", "\\\\+")
); 

 WITH what AS (
      SELECT 1 as id_what, 'c++' as name_what union all 
      SELECT 2 as id_what, 'foo' as name_what

    ),
    andwhere as (
      SELECT 3 as id_where, 'c++ is great' as name_where union all 
      SELECT 5 as id_where, 'c++ was after c' as name_where union all 
      SELECT 4 as id_where, 'food was good' as name_where

    ) 

    SELECT * 
    FROM what join andwhere 
    on regexp_contains(encode_with_escape(andwhere.name_where), encode_with_escape(what.name_what))
```

Gives back:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Pratik. I used some of your code as template, however _"unlocking new issues"_ . With your template however, the issue got solved below. Best regards!

Comment: Hi @DavidEspinosa, happy to be of any help here. I'm glad your issue got resolved that way u wanted it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Pratik's solution is the way to go. Meantime, consider also below option

```
SELECT c.id_what, c.name_what, s.id_where, s.name_where
FROM `my-project.my-database.what-to-query` c, `my-project.my-database.where-to-query` s
WHERE s.name_where LIKE '%' || c.name_what || '%'
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, it seems I am running out of resources when running this query, as the error message `Query exceeded resource limits. This query used 17356 CPU seconds but would charge only 20M Analysis bytes. This exceeds the ratio supported by the on-demand pricing model. Please consider moving this workload to the flat-rate reservation pricing model, which does not have this limit. 17356 CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than 5100 CPU seconds.` appears. This is weird, as the tables have a size of less than 1MB each.

Comment: this makes sense, since you use cross join and in general LIKE is quite expensive function :o) Luckily you have solution provided by Pratik :o)

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail, unfortunately Pratik's answer does not quite match my use case. If possible, please check the updated problem description, as well as the associated attempt at its solution.

Comment: sure, will take a look later in a day :o)

Comment: please see  new answer